# IO::Select to look for user input while runing a continuos check. How to exit?

Tags: perl

Im using IO::Select to look for user input while running a continuous check in the mean time. This works, however, once the input is received the loop will not exit. How to exit? here is some test code:

```
my $timeout = 2;
my $tmp_input = IO::Select->new();
$tmp_input->add(\*STDIN);
my $input;
my $stop = 0;
while ($stop == 0){
    if (my @ready = $tmp_input->can_read($timeout)){
        $stop = 1;
        for my $fh (@ready){
            $input = <$fh>;
        }
    }else{
        timecheck();
    }
}
```

Comment: Using blocking reads (e.g. `<$fh>`) defies the purpose of using `select`, and changing to `sysread` means you can read more than one line. As such, the concept of existing the loop doesn't make any sense (unless you have a large loop that reexecutes this code to get the next line from STDIN). Seems to me you want something like Term::ReadKey

Comment: i would like to call the timecheck() subroutine once every min. while waiting for user input. when the user enters a string of variable length, i want to stop the whole process and do something with the input. could you extrapolate on why what I'm doing "does not make sense"?

Comment: What do you plan on doing if you end up reading the seven characters `abc\ndef` (where `\n` represents an actual newline)?

Comment: while the input is of variable length, it must be one of a few things in a set. if it is not it is caught and a message is displayed. the process is in a loop, and while the program waits for the "correct" input it runs the sub timecheck() once a min.

Comment: it would seem I answer my own question. But eliminating a few un-necessaries and cleaning up my code i have it working see below.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

after cleaning up the code this does what the question specifies:
    use warnings;
    use strict;
    use IO::Select;

```
my $tmp_in = IO::Select->new();
$tmp_in->add(\*STDIN);
my $stop = 0;
while ($stop == 0) {
     &timecheck();
     if ($tmp_in->can_read(5)) {
          chomp(my $input = <STDIN>);
          print "Got $input\n";
          $stop = 1;
     }
}

sub timecheck
{
     print "do you like my hat?\n";
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Is IO::Select required? Because it's just a tool. The problem itself as you stated it:

> i would like to call the timecheck() subroutine once every min. while waiting for user input. when the user enters a string of variable length, i want to stop the whole process and do something with the input

...does not seem to require it. It can be done with EV, for example:

```
#!/usr/bin/env perl

use warnings;
use strict;
use EV;

my $periodic = EV::timer 0, 2, sub
{
  print "timecheck\n";
};

my $user_input = EV::io *STDIN, EV::READ, sub
{
  my ($w, $revents) = @_;
  chomp(my $input = <STDIN>);
  printf "processing your data (%s)...\n", $input;
  EV::break if $input eq 'quit';
};

EV::run;
```

It's unclear whether input "stops" the program for processing or stops it completely, but that may be changed easily.